# Series of Riemann Zeta values analytic continuation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

What is the value of the series?:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac {\zeta(-k)} k$$

Where $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann Zeta function and for every negative integer $n$ we have $\zeta(n)=-\frac {B_{n+1}} {n+1}$.

I know the identity:

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k\frac {\zeta(k)} k=\gamma$$

(where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant) which is pretty similar so I was thinking if the series I wrote converges too ? Is there any closed form for the result ?

Comment: Given the specific [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) between [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) and the Riemann $\zeta$ function at negative integers, the series diverges.

Comment: @Lucian is there a method to make it converge ? Maybe with Ramanujan summation...